# write pc uptime in a file in shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, uptime

I need to log PC uptime. How I can do this?

I use `uptime` for this and I will when ubuntu is shutdown write this command output in a file.

Comment: have you tried steps which i posted

Comment: @RahulPatil Thanks. Yes, i tested it and works fine :). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu

then add below lines in "/etc/rc0.d/S60umountroot" at the beginning.

```
Log="/var/log/uptime.log"
echo "$(date) $(/usr/bin/uptime)" >> "${Log}"
```

or you can simply use `logger`

```
logger "UPTIME: $(uptime)"
```

then it will gives details in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`

Note :- Please careful edit this file

If you are using CentOs, then do the same in "/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/S01halt", 
but note that it should be added in beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to track the system uptime behavior, try [**tuptime**](https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime) It report the historical and statistical running time of the system, keeping it between each reboot.

```
# tuptime -l
Startup:  1  at  01:30:24 PM 08/10/2015
Uptime:   1 minutes and 24 seconds
Shutdown: OK  at  01:31:48 PM 08/10/2015

Downtime: 6 seconds

Startup:  2  at  01:31:55 PM 08/10/2015
Uptime:   3 days, 20 hours, 15 minutes and 35 seconds

System startups:    2   since   01:30:24 PM 08/10/2015
System shutdowns:   1 ok   -   0 bad
Average uptime:     1 days, 22 hours, 8 minutes and 30 seconds
Average downtime:   3 seconds
Current uptime:     3 days, 20 hours, 15 minutes and 35 seconds   since   01:31:55 PM 08/10/2015
Uptime rate:        100.0 %
Downtime rate:      0.0 %
System uptime:      3 days, 20 hours, 17 minutes and 0 seconds
System downtime:    6 seconds
System life:        3 days, 20 hours, 17 minutes and 6 seconds
```